# When open an image using imread with no second argument, what is the color mode? BGR or RGB?

Tags: c++, opencv

The problem is when I need to convert it to HSV, CV_BGR2HSV and CV_RGB2HSV give me different results:
So I really need to know what is the order of color when open by `imread` or how to force the `imread` to open an image in any particular order.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The OpenCV docs for [imread](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) state that by default for 3-channel color images the data is stored in BGR order, e.g. in your Mat, the data is stored as a 1D unsigned char pointer, such that any given color pixel at index `px_idx` is 3 elements in order, with `[px_idx + 0]`: blue channel, `[px_idx + 1]`: green channel, `[px_idx + 2]`: red channel

> Note In the case of color images, the decoded images will have the channels stored in B G R order.

You have some (limited) control over the color type via the flag parameter you pass to `imread`, although you can't specify the channel ordering (you should assume all color images will be BGR)

> CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH - If set, return 16-bit/32-bit image when the input has the corresponding depth, otherwise convert it to 8-bit.
>
> CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR - If set, always convert image to the color one
>
> CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE - If set, always convert image to the grayscale one

Or more simply,

> `>0 Return a 3-channel color image.` (same as CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
>
> `=0 Return a grayscale image.` (same as CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
>
> `<0 Return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel).` (same as CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, as you said: `any given color pixel at index px_idx is 3 elements in order, with [px_idx + 0]: red channel, [px_idx + 1]: green channel, [px_idx + 2]: blue channel`, so from 0 to 2 you have R,G,B respectively. That means the default order of channels is RGB, not BGR?

Answer (score 8):

Are you showing the images using `imshow()`?

`imshow()` actually does not know the color space and **will print images as BGR**, even though you convert them into another format. This is why you get weird results.

To convince yourself, try to convert your image from RGB to BGR and print it using `imshow()`, then do the same by converting from BGR to RGB:

```
cv::cvtColor(src, dst, CV_RGB2BGR);
imshow("RGB2BGR", dst);

cv::cvtColor(src, dst, CV_BGR2RGB);
imshow("BGR2RGB", dst);
```

Then, what your example proves is that converting a BGR image to HSV **will not result** in the same matrix as converting an RGB image to HSV.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that it doesn't make much sense to have imshow() displaying an HSV image, the idea is to see if there's any difference between the HSV converted using CV_BGR2HSV and using CV_RGB2HSV. E.g. if they're identical they should be displayed identically even using imshow or imwrite to a file or any other ways.